# Generating xml from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

For a given claim I have 3 diagnosis codes. Currently while generating xml from SQL Server, I get 3 branches one for each diagnosis code with same claim id as displayed in below output. But I need a way out so that all the 3 diagnosis code can be clubbed with the associated claim id and produce desire result snippet.

Select statement is :

```
select * 
from sandbox.dbo.testing 
WHERE claimID = 20
FOR XML auto,ELEMENTS
```

The output is

```
claimID diagnosis
20  v234
20  v24
20  v256
```

The XML generated is:

```
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
   <claimID>20</claimID>
   <diagnosis>v234</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
   <claimID>20</claimID>
   <diagnosis>v24</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
   <claimID>20</claimID>
   <diagnosis>v256</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>
```

But need the result in below form

```
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
   <claimID>20</claimID>
   <diagnosis>v234</diagnosis>
   <diagnosis>v24</diagnosis>
   <diagnosis>v256</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the rows in a subquery and hard code or use a parameter for the claimID in the main query.

```
select 20 as claimID,
       (
       select diagnosis 
       from sandbox.dbo.testing
       where claimID = 20
       for xml path(''), type
       )
for xml path('sandbox.dbo.testing')
```

Comment: Thank You... It worked.. But in case when No of diagnosis code is not fixed then how to apply... Code can vary from 1 to 50 for a claim id

Comment: Use a parameter `@claimID` and replace the value `20` with `@claimID` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Xml Path()` and `Root`

```
SELECT *
FROM   sandbox.dbo.testing
WHERE  claimID = 20
FOR xml path(''), root('sandbox.dbo.testing')
```

Comment: After using xml path() and root, I am get output in below form:
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
  <claimID>20</claimID>
  <diagnosis>v234</diagnosis>
  <claimID>20</claimID>
  <diagnosis>v24</diagnosis>
  <claimID>20</claimID>
  <diagnosis>v256</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>/

But I need it in this way 
<sandbox.dbo.testing>
  <claimID>20</claimID>
  <diagnosis>v234</diagnosis>  
  <diagnosis>v24</diagnosis>
  <diagnosis>v256</diagnosis>
</sandbox.dbo.testing>

Comment: @Robin - Can post the result of `select * from  sandbox.dbo.testing 
WHERE claimID=20`

Comment: the output is 
claimID diagnosis
20 v234
20 v24
20 v256

Comment: @Robin - Please update this in question in table format

Comment: @Robin - sure gimme some time